# Couldn't get access to IOTA cool network? What is IOTA cool?

Tags: android-wallet, iota-network

I changed the node in the Android wallet and suddenly it said

> Connection Error: No connection to the iota.cool network could be established. [translated]

What is the iota cool network? The name of the node was different and also after changing the node again I had the same error.

This was the error shown in the Android wallet, look at the text at the bottom in German.

[image: Look at the text at the bottom in German]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Android wallet tries to retrieve latest transactions from [http://iota.cool](http://iota.cool/load/current_transactions?max=500&tag=&spam=false&mst=false&nonzero=true&uncut=true)—if that fails, this notification is shown. This site seems to be down at the moment. But apart from the fact that the explorer view does not show any recent transactions, the wallet should still work fine.

Here is the source code that does this on [github](https://github.com/iotaledger/android-wallet-app/blob/d6044cf0db1c7e3f3362f32854e0a525b327501f/app/src/main/java/org/iota/wallet/api/handler/CoolTransactionsRequestHandler.java#L55-L71).